# solve for x using inequalities

Tags: inequality

Solve

$$\frac{x}{x-2} < \frac{x}{x-1}$$

I know for inequality you have to multiply by the denominator square but I'm not sure if this applies to this one since this contains two denominators.

Comment: Where have you arrived so far?

Comment: I multiplied the left hand side by x-2 and the right hand side by x-1 and simplified and then I took the right hand side over to the left hand side and was left with -x

Comment: For future reference, include your work in your post. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4):

An inequality is preserved if you multiply both sides by a positive number, and reversed if you multiply both sides by a negative number.

Actually, what I would do in this case is subtract the left side from the right and express over a common denominator.  The inequality becomes

$$ 0 < \dfrac{x}{x-1} - \dfrac{x}{x-2} = \dfrac{-x}{(x-1)(x-2)} \tag{1}$$
Now there are three $x$ values at which this changes sign: $x = 0,1,2$.
Those values themselves don't give solutions, because they make the right side of (1) either $0$ or undefined.
Starting from the right and moving to the left on the number line:

- If $x > 2$, then $x$, $x-1$, and $x-2$ are all positive, so the right side of (1) is negative, not positive.  No solutions here.
- If $1 < x < 2$, the factor $x-2$ has changed sign, becoming negative, so the right side of (1) is positive, which is what we want.
- If $0 < x < 1$, the factor $x-1$ is also negative, and the right side is negative again.
- If $x < 0$, the factors $x$, $x-1$, $x-2$ are all negative, and the right side is positive again.

Thus the solutions are $x < 0$ and $1 < x < 2$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\frac{x}{x-2}<\frac{x}{x-1} &\implies (x-1)^2 (x-2)^2 \frac{x}{x-2} < (x-1)^2 (x-2)^2 \frac{x}{x-1}\\
&\implies x (x-1)^2 (x-2) < x(x-1)(x-2)^2\\
&\implies x^4 - 4x^3 + 5x^2 -2x < x^4 - 5x^3 + 8x^2 - 4x\\
&\implies  - 4x^3 + 5x^2 -2x < - 5x^3 + 8x^2 - 4x\\
&\implies -x^3 + 3x^2 - 2x > 0\\
\end{align}

Solve $-x^3 + 3x^2 - 2x = 0$ and you will obtain $x = 0, 1, 2$.

Evaluate values in $(-\infty, 0)$, in $(0, 1)$ in $(1, 2)$ and finally in $(2, +\infty)$ and you will see that:

- In $(-\infty, 0) \cup (1, 2)$ the inequality is verified.
- In $(0, 1)$ and $(2, +\infty)$, it is not verified.

So:
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{x-2}<\frac{x}{x-1} &\implies x < 0 \text{  or  } 1 < x < 2\end{align}